# Photo Gallery Share not showing my app ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, share, photo

I want my app to be listed among other shareable resources (such as WhatsApp, Instagram etc.) in Photo Gallery. I have read many articles on Stack Overflow but was unable to list my app there. I have added the following in my list. But still cant see my app. What else do I need to do?

The bundle id for both app and extension is same which is in reverse order of domain (ie com.xxx.xxx)

[image: iphone5 error]
[image: App's App Group Detail]
[image: Extension's App Group]
[image: Extension's PLIST]

```
 <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Images</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Alternate</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.image</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your host application's bundle identifier must be prefixed in your extension's bundle identifier.

for example if your host app's bundle identifier is "com.mycompany.hostapp" then extension's bundle identifier must be "com.mycompany.hostapp.myextension"